# На Руси

Tags: предлог

Говорят "в Киевской Руси", но при этом почему-то "на Руси". Почему так?

Comment: Кстати, "в России". Наверное "Русь" воспринимается не просто как государство.

Comment: Разумеется. Но мысль как-то связывать выбор предлога с политическим статусом "не только непг'авильная, но аг'хивг'едная"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Особенно в свете непрекращающихся лингво-политических игр вокруг В/НА Украине.

Предлог "НА" издревне употребляется по отношению к широким, протяженным во всех отношения объектам: на острове, на озере, на севере (и на Севере), на Кавказе, на Руси и проч., хотя есть и обратные примеры: в пустыне и т.д.

Русь (как и Украина) воспринималась именно таким географическим, ландшафтным объектом. 
При этом любое сужение смысла с помощью прилагательных или других слов (независимо от семантики) часто приводит к замене предлога: в (дальней) части озера, в горах Кавказа, в Северном Кипре и проч.
Видимо что-то подобное имеет место и в отношении "Киевской Руси". Есще раз подчеркуну, напрямую с тем, что Киевская Русь - государство, это не связано.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в данных случаях проявляются сложившиеся в речи традиции употребления предлогов В и НА. Подобное можно встретить нередко. Пример: жить в свободной Украине - жить на Украине. Правда, со словом Украина в последние годы произошла метаморфоза: сейчас принято говорить "в Украине", но не все принимают такую форму, хотя она вполне объяснима, ведь предлог "в" употребляется очень часто в подобных случаях (в Грузии, в Армении, в Киргизии).