# На или в Древней/Киевской Руси?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, выбор-слов, предлоги, управление

Похожий вопрос уже [обсуждался](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10165/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8), однако исчерпывающего ответа, кажется, дано не было. Предлагаю поднять вопрос еще раз и затем, если получится, объединить ответы.

Как и почему лучше: *в* или *на* Древней (Киевской) Руси? Есть ли кодифицированный вариант?

Comment: *Как* правильно – даже из ваших статистических данных видно. Было бы еще яснее, если бы вы привели источники, где написано "на Древней Руси".

Comment: Также обитает в Аравии, Персии, Китае. Близкородственные виды встречались на Древней Руси. [Птица Феникс // «Пятое измерение», 2003]

Comment: Одним из любых блюд на Древней Руси была каша, в которую...( Что ели древние славяне?);   На древней Руси любили только толстых женщин, а худых не любили...(Палата №6 on Twitter);  История туризма - Гостеприимство на древней Руси (Гостеприимство на древней Руси - Страница 17)...    Таких перлов достаточно, но их в РАЗЫ меньше, чем  "в Древней Руси"

Answer (score 1):

Пространственные предлоги НА и В,употребляющиеся с предложным падежом, синонимичны, иногда взаимозаменяемы, иногда различаются тонкими оттенками. При этом семантика НА шире.

НА употребляется

1. при обозначении поверхности, площади какого-нибудь предмета, являющейся местом проявления какого-нибудь действия. Например: на улице большое движение; гулять на бульваре; "Я молча сел на краю стола" (Пушкин); жить на Крайнем Севере (ср.: на Украине, на Корсике, на Аляске и т. п.); сидеть на стуле; на столе стоит посуда; писать на плотной бумаге.;

   при названиях горных областей для обозначения места действия: на Кавказе, на Урале (но ср. по отношению к горным областям Западной Европы: в Швейцарии, в Тироле; также при названиях государств: в Испании, в Норвегии и т. п.);

   при обозначении предмета или лица как поверхности, площади, являющейся местом нахождения, обнаружения чего-нибудь. Например: живопись на фарфоре; царапины на носу; гардины на окнах; на нем шляпа и новое пальто; на ногах туфли.

Переносно употребляется при обозначении предмета, который мыслится как фон проявления и сосредоточения какого-нибудь душевного состояния:на душе какая-то тяжесть; тоска на сердце.

2.(наряду с предлогом В) при обозначении предмета, пространства, в пределах которого происходит, замыкается проявление какого-нибудь действия, свойства. Например: Первый на селе работник; На предприятиях и в учреждении идет предвыборная кампания.

// В отличие от предлога В, обозначающего лишь область, сферу в пределах которой что-нибудь происходит, обозначает одновременно и сферу, место действия, и сопричастность действию, участие пассивное или активное в какой-нибудь деятельности: сидеть на лекции; быть на концерте (но: быть в театре); работать на заводе (но: работать в мастерской); учиться на курсах, на медицинском факультете, на рабфаке (но: учиться в институте, в университете).

*Одним из любых блюд **на Древней Руси** была каша, в которую...*- на всём пространстве Древней Руси.

***В Древней Руси*** любимым блюдом была каша - в пределах Древней Руси как государства.

Получается, **НА Древней/Киевской Руси** - имеется в виду место действия как **площадь** проявления действия,подчёркивается сопричастность жизни народа на всём пространстве(народное выражение, образное); **В Древней/Киевской Руси -** имеется в виду место действия как **государство**(нейтральное литературное).

Answer (score 0):

С первого взгляда может показаться, что пространственные предлоги «В» и « НА» с предложным языком различаются всего лишь тонкими оттенками. Однако, если серьёзно разобраться в этих оттенках, то их различия уходят корнями в конкретно обозначенные критерии распределения и чётко коррелируют не только с данными экстралингвистической действительности, но и с тем, как русское языковое мышление воспринимает и обрабатывает  эту действительность.
Предлог «В» предполагает значения явного или неявного  (скрытого) ограничения пространства/места/, в котором  находится объект или субъект в активном или пассивном состоянии. Ограничение может быть не только   конкретным, осязаемым, но и абстрактно-ментальным. Понимание ограничения как невозможности легко и произвольно выйти из любой точки данного пространства в «антипространство» («в комнате», «в доме») в широком толковании может быть понято и как представление об опасности затеряться (и поэтому не выйти) в этом пространстве. Отсюда «В степи, в горах, в тайге, в лесу». 
В противовес этому если пространство открыто («на улице, на площади»), неограничено («на солнце, на воздухе, на свободе, или на островах»), малоограничено и не представляет собой угрозу затеряться («на окраине, на краю, на юге, на севере, на западе, на востоке, но в центре» здесь ограничено), с меняющимися, или внутренними/неважными, размытыми границами («На Луганщине, на Смоленщине,») ограничено по времени, что тоже реально невидимо, но ощутимо («на уроке, на концерте, на выставке, в театре, но на спектакле»).
Теперь о душевном состоянии: к приведённым примерам хочу внести существенное объяснение. Когда речь идёт о чём-то негативном, что давит на человека, мучает его, то мы говорим: «На душе тоскливо, на сердце тяжело». Если же субъект испытывает нечто приятное, но затаённое где-то в собственной чувственной глубине, то о нём можно сказать, к примеру: «В душе он ценил/любил её». Предлог «В» обоснован факторами «затаённость, скрытость, глубина». Перечитывая этот абзац, я решила подкорректировать свой собственный комментарий. Ведь можно сказать не только «на душе тоскливо», но и «на душе светло». Скорее всего речь здесь не именно о негативных чувствах, а о состоянии души вообще, тогда как в варианте с  предлогом «В» имеет место желание скрыть эти чувства и мысли в глубину 
Дальше вопрос с «сидением на». Со стулом всё понятно. Но вот другой пример: можно «сидеть в кресле» - значит углублённое или погружённое сидение. Но можно «сидеть на кресле», если сидеть на широком подлокотнике этого кресла.
При обозначении стран и городов как правило мы говорим с предлогом «В», потому что в голове сидит понимание того, что где-то на бумаге обозначены границы этих мест, даже если мы эти границы не всегда видим. Если кто-нибудь, к примеру, проживает у самой границы какого-нибудь города, откуда ему быстрее, чем иному, проживающему в самом городе, можно добраться до центра этого города, первый всё равно по адресу проживает вне города. Это и доказывает тот факт, что у города есть нами не видимая граница.
К вопросу об Украине. Вариант «На Украине» сильно обижает украинцев, потому что они видят в этом намёк на недогосударственное образование на окраине России с непонятными размытыми границами (по типу «на окраине» смотрите выше). Мне думается, что русский человек, не желая отказаться от варианта «на Украине», подспудно высказывает своё ощущение того, что то, что к сегодняшнему дню сформировалось под новым названием «Украина», продолжает оставаться исторической Родиной всех восточных славян, ведь мы говорим «Я побывал на Родине, а не (в Родине)», то есть «на Украине» сродни «на Родине». Скорее всего здесь речь идёт о чувственном восприятии понятия Родина.

С другой стороны, в русском языке есть слово «Отечество», и мы говорим «в Отечестве» 
(«нет пророка в Отечестве своём»).  Слово «Отечество» это огосударствленный вариант слова «Родина». Ведь мы говорим «развитие отечественного машиностроение», но не говорим «производство родного машиностроения»). Здесь, конечно, имеется ввиду не государственное, а личное отношение. Зато на Родине принято что-то делать как-то по-особенному: танцевать, петь, жарить, варить и т.д. Точно так же мы можем высказывать разные мысли по-разному: если мы говорим о том, что в этой стране народ думает, поёт, танцует, готовит какие-то блюда, что-то практикует как-то по-особенному, то скорее всего хочется сказать «На Украине», по аналогий с «на Родине». («На Украине принято, думают, говорят…»)
А если речь идёт о каких-то государственных делах, законах, указах, реформах, то есть всего того, что направлено на формирование и укрепление Отчизны, то следовало бы приучить себя говорить: «В Украине», коль Россия уж признала её независимость.
По той же логике, думаю, можно объяснить распределение вариантов «На Древней Руси» и «В Древней Руси».
Итак: Родина- На Украине- На Древней Киевской Руси, когда речь идёт о жизни народа с одной стороны, и Отчизна – В Украине – В Древней Киевской Руси, когда речь идёт о государственных делах и о становлении государственности – с другой стороны.
В заключении хочу признаться, что всё вышеизложенное является плодом моих собственных рассуждений, основанных на многолетнем опыте преподавания русского языка, и если кто не согласен со мной, пожалуйста, возмущайтесь вежливо. Я приму любые комментарии. Есть ещё просьбы не политизировать мои размышления об Украине. Спасибо.